# Choosing bonding mode between RHEL server and two separate switches

Tags: rhel6, bonding

I have one RHEL 6 server with two NIC ports (each Port is connected to different switch).  I need to create bonded interface from those two physical ports.

Which bonding mode should I use? I don't want to use mode 1, active /backup won't help me with performance.

Please be informed that two switches are totally separated switches. (no stacking, no cascading).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well your valid options are:

> **balance-rr or 0** — Sets a round-robin policy for fault tolerance and
> load balancing. Transmissions are received and sent out sequentially
> on each bonded slave interface beginning with the first one available.
>
> **active-backup or 1** — Sets an active-backup policy for fault tolerance.
> Transmissions are received and sent out via the first available bonded
> slave interface. Another bonded slave interface is only used if the
> active bonded slave interface fails.
>
> **balance-xor or 2** — Sets an XOR
> (exclusive-or) policy for fault tolerance and load balancing. Using
> this method, the interface matches up the incoming request's MAC
> address with the MAC address for one of the slave NICs. Once this link
> is established, transmissions are sent out sequentially beginning with
> the first available interface.
>
> **broadcast or 3** — Sets a broadcast
> policy for fault tolerance. All transmissions are sent on all slave
> interfaces.
>
> **802.3ad or 4** — Sets an IEEE 802.3ad dynamic link aggregation policy. Creates aggregation groups that share the same speed and duplex
> settings. Transmits and receives on all slaves in the active
> aggregator. Requires a switch that is 802.3ad compliant.
>
> **balance-tlb or 5** — Sets a Transmit Load Balancing (TLB) policy for fault tolerance
> and load balancing. The outgoing traffic is distributed according to
> the current load on each slave interface. Incoming traffic is received
> by the current slave. If the receiving slave fails, another slave
> takes over the MAC address of the failed slave.
>
> **balance-alb or 6** — Sets an Active Load Balancing (ALB) policy for fault tolerance and
> load balancing. Includes transmit and receive load balancing for IPV4
> traffic. Receive load balancing is achieved through ARP negotiation.

You've already eliminated `active-backup` since it doesn't give you the performance gains you're after.

`broadcast` won't give you performance gains, and `802.3ad` is out since you can't do that with disparate switches.

So that leaves you with `balance-rr`, `balance-xor`, `balance-tlb` or `balance-alb`. Without knowing your workload, you'll be best off to test each method to see which gives you the best performance for your workload.

Don't forget you can tweak `xmit_hash_policy` as well which may improve your performance in `balance-xor` mode.

Comment: Hi Fukawi2, Thanks for your reply. I have tried balance tlb/alb and balance xor. With balance tlb and balance alb,I can ping to IP address of bond for 10 sec when server is booting up. And I can't ping to bond IP anymore until I restart the network service.  When I change mode to 2 balance xor,  it is okay and working fine. However some people said I need to configure switches to use balance xor.  Is that true?

Comment: No matter what option you choose, you will never be able to increase the throughput to a single host, even with balance-rr. You will always be sending to a single MAC address, which will always end up at a single port.

Comment: Not quite; with `xmit_hash_policy=1` and `balance-xor` you can spread different CONNECTIONS to the same host over multiple slaves.

Comment: Actually you can do Mode 4 to two switches, you'll just have two link bundles which fail over when a switch goes down.